# The type or namespace name 'IBM' could not be found (when loading IBM.Data.DB2.DLL

Tags: .net, db2

Am running VS 2017 / NET 4.5.2 on my workstation. I've installed IBM.Data.DB2.DLL 9.7.4.4 on my workstation. From my workstation, I'm able to connect to a production DB2 database, open it, read from it, and write to it. When I had my build deployed to the application server, I immediately get the error in the title when the app first loads (before any operation is performed from the app or even before the 1st page appears). I have no access to the application server to interrogate what DLLs are installed on it. I've searched for a solution but not finding one.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

This is little hard to answer when you are not sure about the server configuration you are deploying to.
Your build can fail on the server for the following factors.

The Server

1. doesn't have an IBM client installed or
2. has a different Version or different bit version(32/64 bit) than what your project has referenced

If you know that the server has the client installed and assume it to be the same version, maybe you can try the "Copy Local" property against the "IBM.Data.DB2.DLL" in your project solution. This uses the DLL from your project folder instead of trying to locate in the server's assemblies. 
[Copy Local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTtRZ.jpg)

There could be other factors too, like firewall access on the target server to the database etc. If you could give a little more details, it will be easy to provide you with a specific solution.